# Is the following proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus rigorous throughout?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

We begin by letting a function of $t$, $f$, be continuous on the interval $[a,b]$. We then assume there exists a function that is defined as the area between the curve of $f$ and the $t$-axis on the closed interval $[a,b]$ from $a$ to some value, $x$, such that $a\leq x\leq b$. Let this function be $F(x)$. Therefore, by definition:$$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)~dt$$ If we were to then take the derivative $F(x)$, we would find that $$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$$ $$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\int_a^{x+h}f(t)~dt-\int_a^xf(t)~dt\right]\tag{1}$$$($The reason for writing the derivative the way it's written in $(1)$ is for appeal$)$. If we subtract the area between the curve of $f$ and the $t$-axis from $a$ to $x$ from the same area, but from $a$ to $x+h$, we arrive at the same area, but from $x$ to $x+h$. What this means for the most recent step in the working is that $$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)~dt$$From this step, we resort to the *Mean Value Theorem* for integrals.

> *Mean Value Theorem:* For every continuous function, $g$, on the closed interval $[a,b]$, $$\exists c\in[a,b]:\int_a^bg(x)~dx=g(c)(b-a)$$ $$\implies g(c)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bg(x)~dx$$

What this means for the most recent step in our working is that since we now know that there is some value, $c:c\in[x,x+h]$, and $$\int_x^{x+h}f(t)~dt=f(c)~h$$ $$\implies f(c)=\frac{1}{h}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)~dt$$For the sake of later stages in the proof, we will also mention that the value of $c$ is given as a function of $h$. Furthermore, we now have that $$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}~f(c)$$now, for us to take the limit, we must consider what happens to the value of $c$, as $h\to0$, and for this purpose, we start with what we know, which is that $$x\leq c(h)\leq x+h$$ $$\implies \lim_{h\to0}~x\leq \lim_{h\to0}~c(h)\leq \lim_{h\to0}~x+h$$ $$x\leq \lim_{h\to0}~c(h)\leq x$$hence, by the squeeze theorem, $$\implies \lim_{h\to0}~c(h)=x$$and therefore $$F'(x)=f(x)$$ The question is then, are all of these steps legitimately rigorous? I understand that assuming there exists a function that gives the area between the $t$-axis and the curve of $f$ might create some issues, but I'm not sure what these issues might be. Another area that I'm uncertain of is defining $c$ as a function of $h$, and whether or not that step is even necessary? Any feedback is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Roughly yes ... looks good. Same proof technique is used by [wikipedia article on this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)

Comment: Yes, you do need to define $c$ as a function of $h$. But everything is fine... unless you find someone who doesn't like the axiom of choice.